# Export to csv/xls with a template

Tags: export

I have a customer who is an old-aged volunteer and is not so familiar to spreadsheets but still needs to use them until the whole database is imported and I want to make the export from CiviCRM easier to use for her.

I know this is a weird question because the first answer is: "don't use spreadsheet or at least learn how to use them" but I was wondering if there is a way / extension to help doing this:

- export to excel with the possibility of choosing and arranging columns

Any Idea?

regards,

Guilllaume

Answer (score 1):

To address the export to excel part of the question, you can use this (well-written and maintained) extension:

https://civicrm.org/extensions/export-native-excel

But the field ordering is harder - by default, you can't change that.

Comment: Actually, I already have this extension. My question was about having a kind of tool that would let me reorder and choose the columns I want to export. This is a self-made tool I had in another company and I was wondering if something had existed for CiviCRM

Answer (score 0):

You can get part of this by using the constituent summary civireport and choosing the desired columns and saving that as an instance, then using the export to csv action from the dropdown.

But it's not a complete list of fields and you can't reorder them.